# Intel RST (option rom, bios) raid and mdamd, how to?

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

I have 4 x 6TB hard drives which has been setup for RAID 10 in the BIOS (option rom: Intel RST (v12.7.0.1936)) on my P6T7 WS ASUS Motherboard with modded bios ([BIOS](https://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20150226024739199&board_id=1&model=P6T7%20WS%20SuperComputer&page=1&SLanguage=en-us)) which works  :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul 29 00:06 /dev/raidDevice1 -> sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul 29 00:06 /dev/raidDevice2 -> sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul 29 00:06 /dev/raidDevice3 -> sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jul 29 00:06 /dev/raidDevice4 -> sdj
```

When I start Ubuntu 14.04 -> (mdadm is installed)
then i get some kind of device mapper devices (dm0/dm1/dm2)?
What are those? Are these already my raid? But it should be only one device and exactly 12TB big (Raid 10, 4 Hds 6TB = 12TB)?

`lsblk` gives:

```
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0   5.5T  0 disk    
└─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0-1 (dm-0) 252:0    0   1.5T  0 dmraidi 
  └─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0 (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.9T  0 dmraid  
sdb                              8:16   0   5.5T  0 disk    
└─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0-0 (dm-1) 252:1    0   1.5T  0 dmraidi 
  └─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0 (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.9T  0 dmraid  
sdc                              8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk    
└─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0-0 (dm-1) 252:1    0   1.5T  0 dmraidi 
  └─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0 (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.9T  0 dmraid  
sdj                              8:144  0   5.5T  0 disk    
└─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0-1 (dm-0) 252:0    0   1.5T  0 dmraidi 
  └─isw_biajiifeeg_vol0 (dm-2) 252:2    0   2.9T  0 dmraid
```

The disk utility shows the following:

[image: diskutil]

I dont know what to do now to use this raid 10 configuration?
Should I still doo the following setup as described in (page: 9 in [INTEL PDF MANUAL](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/rst-linux-paper.pdf))
 which is:

```
 mdadm -C /dev/md/imsm /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdj -n 4 -e imsm
 mdadm -C /dev/md/vol0 /dev/md/imsm –n 3 –l 10
```

Does somebody know what to do know or do differently?
I actually wanted to delete the funny devices `/dev/dm*` `mdadm --remove /dev/dm0`

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it:

THe problem was that dmraid (the former mdadm) wos installed which is legacy,
I uninstalled that via apt-get.
Then created the raid with

```
 mdadm -C /dev/md/imsm /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdj -n 4 -e imsm
 mdadm -C /dev/md/vol0 /dev/md/imsm –n 3 –l 10
```

And now the output looks like this (AWESOME :)

[image]